# Need help replacing filenames in c#

Tags: c#

I want to replace 6 random files in specified directories. My only problem with the code is that I want to give the `.txt` only the name I have in the `asd` string, because now it just adds it to the end.

My code:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\patri\\Desktop\\asd");
string[] asd = { "kutya", "cica", "kacsa", "liba", "kék", "zöld" };

for (int index = 0; index < fajlok.Length; index++)
    System.IO.File.Move(fajlok[index], fajlok[index].Insert(fajlok[index].IndexOf(".txt"), asd[index]));

Console.WriteLine("1. átnevezés megtörtént! (nyomjon meg egy billentyűt)");
Console.ReadKey();
fajlok = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\patri\\Desktop\\lul");

for (int index = 0; index < fajlok.Length; index++)
    System.IO.File.Move(fajlok[index], fajlok[index].Insert(fajlok[index].IndexOf(".txt"), asd[index]));

Console.WriteLine("2. átnevezés megtörtént! (nyomjon meg egy billentyűt)");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, Im guessing partly english may not be your first language. However, Id guess part of your issue is that you're trying to reinvent the wheel.  c# has a number of functions to allow you to grab filenames, extensions etc so you can safely manipulate the filenames.

Comment: Just a guess, is the `var files` meant to be the same variable as `fajlok` in the rest of the code sample? If so, please [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48153354/edit).

Comment: Peter: Yes it wsupposed to be it but i couldn't post it because the site didn't let me but it's the same.
BugFinder: It's just i want to delete the current file name and enter a new one

Comment: How about using the FileInfo class in .NET?

Comment: My real problem Mark is that I can't because I'm an autistic guy, and I tried to do everything in it but it got red marks and i tried to write almost all combination but still failed. Can you please help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want to rename the file using just the base filenames in `asd`, and with the extension ".txt".

If that is all indeed, then this would be the solution:

```
using System.IO; // gives access to classes File and Path

...
File.Move(fajlok[index], Path.GetDirectoryName(fajlok[index]) + "\\" + asd[index] + ".txt");
```

For some documentation see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for helping me, even when I was a little bit too retarded.

Comment: Don't worry, we are all here to learn.